# Conditional query in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Sample Document

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("612b5d4bbc1bed7ce5d5oa66"),
    "username": "test",
    "user_details": {}
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("612b5d4bbc1bed7ce5d5oa67"),
    "username": "test",
    "user_details": {
      "name": "Test",
      "addreess": "tets addr",
      "city": "nddj"
    },
    verify_at: ISODate("2021-08-30T10:23:37.558Z")
  }
]
```

I want to fetch those record if user_details is empty object then verify_at should not exist and user_details object has some value then no need to check verify_at exists false
This is what I have tried

```
 $and:[{$or:[{$and:[{user_details:{}},{verify_at:{$exists:false}}]},{$and:{user_details:{$ne:{}}}}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can use this query:

- If `user_details` exists -> Find the element without check `verify_at`
- If `user_details` is `{}` then check if `verify_at` does not exists.

```
yourModel.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "user_details": {
        "$ne": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "$and": [
        {
          "user_details": {}
        },
        {
          "verify_at": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2qirihU1KFN)

Comment: One doubt here is if i have to add condition for other column then will it work yourModel.find({"name":"test",$and:[{"$or":[{"user_details":{"$ne":{}}},{"$and":[{"user_details":{}},{"verify_at":{"$exists":false}}]}]}]})

Comment: Yes, it will work, check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nFw492lb-CU). Also you can add the value into `$and` if you prefer: [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pit_Q6ReiTW)